# Passing repeat object outside the div for function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm new to angular. Anyway I have a table that has data come in from a database via function and this is repeated.

```
<td class="col-md-3">
      <label class="control-label">Corporate Wholesaler Dea</label>
      <div class="dropdown" style="width:100%">
          <input type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-ng-disabled="formReadOnly" data-ng-model="item.CORP_WHOLESALER_DEA" data-ng-keyup="comboBoxOptions(6, 78, item.CORP_WHOLESALER_DEA, 'wholeSalerDeaOptions', 'DEA')" />
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:100%">
              <li data-ng-repeat="name in wholeSalerDeaOptions" style="width:100%"><a data-ng-click="changeData('CORP_WHOLESALER_DEA', name, 'DEA')">{{name}}</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <label class="error" data-ng-show="validate()">Error</label>
</td>
```

Right here the text is looped into the control,

`data-ng-repeat="name in wholeSalerDeaOptions"`

but I would like to get access and pass it to the validate() function.

`<label class="error" data-ng-show="validate()">Error</label>`

Also, how would I pass the current text of `{{name}}`?

The user can change it does it just update the variable when they change it?

Edit: Here is a pic. So, as you can see when you type 1 there are 3 options. If a user picks an option but then changes toi text to one that isnt in that list, the form should not be valid.

[image]

Comment: So someone clicks on the link, `changeData` is called and then you want the error label to show if `name` on the link they clicked is correct/wrong according to the `validate()` result ?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is validate if the text in the text field is = to one of the drop down options. This would be checked in validate()

Comment: While not instant, you can use `data-ng-blur="validate()"` on the `input` control. By then `item.CORP_WHOLESALER_DEA` should have the value selected/typed by the user.